# Quisiera que me mostrara los resultados mas ordenados en JAVA

Tags: java

Quisiera que el resultado de mi compilación me lo mostrara mas ordenado, esto es en programacion java

esto yo lo sabia hacer con otro codigos, el problema que este es diferente.

podrían ayudarme con eso porfis

Adjunto un fragmento del codigo, ya que me arrojaba un error al intentar pegarlo completo:

```
public class Tarea5 {
  public static void main (String args []) {
    try {

    }   
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Lista de curso ");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");    
    System.out.println(" Nombre               Notas P1  Notas P2  Promedio Tareas   trabajo      PROMEDIO FINAL   Situacion final ");   
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s       %.1f          %.1f       %.1f        %.1f        %.1f",names[i], notaP1[i], notaP2[i], promtareas[i], trabajo[i], notafinal[i]); 
        if(notafinal[i]<4) {
           System.out.println(" Reprobado ");
        }
        else {
           System.out.println(" Aprobado ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Promedio Curso: " + promcurso );
    System.out.println ("Desviacion Estandar: " + destandar );
    System.out.println ("Promedio Maximo: " + max + "Nombre: " + nombremayor );
    System.out.println ("Promedio Minimo: " + min + "Nombre: " + nombremenor );   
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(" error del calculo o falta de argumento " +e);
    } 
  } 
}
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: No se como adjuntar el codigo, me dice que mi pregunta es mayormente codigo y que ingrese mas detalles..

Comment: Tu quieres que los datos en consola se muestren con una tabla. Tal como lo haces no se puede conseguir - debes calcular el largo de la cadena que imprimes y cada número ajustarlo a la posición deseada con espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el caracter `\t` (tabulado) en lugar de espacio para que se alinien las columnas.

```
System.out.println(" Nombre\t\tNotas\t\tP1\t\tNotas\t\tP2\t\tPromedio\t\tTareas   trabajo\t\tPROMEDIO FINAL\t\tSituacion final ");
```

Nota: yo use dos para separar las columnas, pero por ahi para alguna columna con un tabulado alcanza y para otra tal vez necesites más, esto depende del largo de los campos.